# Set default printer for each location

Tags: printing, network

Is there a way I can set a different default printer for each network location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sidekick](http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/) will let you do this.

Highly recommended.

("Disclaimer:" I was a beta tester for the new version, but also a paying customer. Otherwise un-affiliated with them.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm noticing (as I travel from office to office with my new MacBook Air) that OS is automatically choosing the appropriate printer as I switch locations.  Is this new in Mountain Lion?  I like it!

Comment: Here's some details on the new functionality: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18608?locale=en_US

Comment: Thank you, but that functionality is no longer "new."  The comment you're replying to is 3.5 years old.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Control Plane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com). It's a rewrite of Marco Polo.

It can change the default printer based on your location or other rules. You can also write your own rules, if you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Marco Polo (available [here](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/)).  It has some flexible rule matching to detect which network you are connected to and then fire off some actions.  One of the actions is to set the default printer.

Sadly, it currently looks unsupported.  The WiFi network input doesn't work under Snow Leopard or Lion.  You might still be able to get other inputs to discriminate among locations, however.

Answer (score 0):

[LocationX](http://homepage.mac.com/locationmanager/) used to be able to do this, it hasn't been updated in a long time though so no idea whether it'll work on 10.6 or 10.7.